# Trying to let users save their profile img. but i keep getting cannot invoke 'user?' with no arguments.

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

trying to let users save their profile img to the storage

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {



        profileImg.image = selectedImage
        let user = User?()
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference()                      
        let imgsReference = ref.child("proimgs")
        let uid = user?.uid
        let newimgReference = imgsReference.child(uid!)
        newimgReference.setValue(["proimgs": self.selectedImage.image!])
print("description: \"(newimgReference.description())")      }  }
```

(btw, sorry i'm very new to coding)

Comment: To determine the current user's UID: `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 0):

`let user = User?()`, it would appear that the `User()` intializer takes some sort of parameters. You did not provide enough context to provide a solution, just point you to the issue. Your code snippet doesn't provide any information on where this User class came from or what it's usage requirements are.

Edit:
On second look, perhaps it's actually the line `let uid = user?.uid`, and the issue is that `user` wasn't properly initialized since you used `User?()` instead of `User()`, and since you didn't specify a type for `user` it has no idea what the property `uid` is.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, please try:

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    ...
}
```

and then use the "user" variable as you are.

Comment: Do not keep the line `let user = User?()` . sorry, I should have specified. the if let will put the information that you want in "user".